# Accessing "Spring MVC" application from a "Java EE Dynamic Web" application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

We have two applications, one is a Java EE Dynamic Web application which is accessed from the Internet with a complex authentication mechanism.
The second one is a new application built on Spring MVC framework (3.0 above). Both applications are deployed on the same WAS server.

Now we need to access some details (like employee details based on an employee id) from the new Spring application to the Java EE web application.

i.e using a method call to the new Spring application from the Java EE web application by passing some parameters (*EmpId*) and also to update some details, etc.

We are not planning to re-authenticate again to the new Spring application.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by "not re-authenticate"? SSO or no authentication?

Comment: Can you separate the "JEE Dynamic Web application" into 2 project. One is the presentation layer and the other is the core business logic. The business logic can not be access from public network. So you can share the business logic on both "old jee application" and "new spring application" by api integration without breaking any of ur authentication.

Comment: @MartinBaumgartner : not to re-authenticate means SSO only

Comment: @Jeff Lee, could you please share more info on how to share business logic? at api level

Answer (score 0):

You must configure both of the Applications to use the same session store in the WAS Server. 
With this when querying the new Spring Application you can pass the url as following;

```
http://<host>:<port>/newapplication/user/1?JSESSIONID=<JavaEEApplicationSessionID>
```

Where `JavaEEApplicationSessionID` is the current JSESSIONID you are already logged into using the Java EE Application. This way the new Spring application will look for the JSESSIONID in the shared session store and will not ask to re-authenticate as it can find a valid session.

Comment: ,thank you for your suggestion, can i directly access any methods at api level? like sharing business logic in "Jeff lee's"  comments above.

Answer (score 0):

As Jeff Lee suggested, you need to split your application **Java EE Style**.

That means your project would become a war file with your web application and a jar file with your EJBs. Then your EJBs (considering they are configured right) would be accessible by both applications.

To achieve that, you will need to pack your **Java EE** application as an EAR file.
Good old Java EE Tutorial from Oracle to give you some guidance.
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/packaging001.htm#BCGDJDFB

That is the fundamental idea behind EJBs. Your piece of business logic would become available (and reusable) across all applications and changes to one of those pieces of BL would reflect across all applications.

Comment: yeah, thank for sharing the detail. But I think that the fundamental of j2ee is using RMI to seperate the business logic. I am not sure you can do a rmi from spring. Should be yes??  But if I do that, i will create a list of API like http://xxxxxx.com/getUser.json in your private network to share the service.

Comment: One more thing the careful is this channel not transactional

Comment: Well, RMI is used behind the scenes, you don't need to use it directly. EJBs get registered in the JNDI and you only need to grab the JNDI and ask for the EJB. The Transactions would be in the EJB side so every call would be enclosed in a transaction.